# 60 column table with 700k rows taking about 30 minutes to go from dataframe to database

Tags: python, pandas, azure, sqlalchemy, azure-sql-database

Wondering if the title sounds normal and what I could possibly do to make this process faster. I am using python to transfer tables over from one Azure SQL database to another. The database I'm inserting tables into is a `General Purpose - Serverless: Standard-series (Gen5), 1 vCore` azure sql database- just in case that helps for context.   From what I've seen online, I feel like this process should be a lot quicker and here's where I've gotten so far:

Here's how I'm creating my engine- I've added fast_executemany=True

```py
engine_azure2 = create_engine(conn_str2,echo=True, fast_executemany=True)
conn2 = engine_azure2.connect()
```

and here's how I've got my to_sql set up- I've seen that I could use `method='multi'` here, however if I've got `fast_executemany=True` inside of the engine creation it just ends up giving me errors.

```py
df.to_sql(table_name, conn2, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000, method=None)
```

Comment: Is your python loader also running in the same Azure zone as the databases? If not, 400 60 column rows per second to read and write to remote cloud databases seems pretty good to me.

Comment: @JonSG So technically this python script is a Timer Trigger that I plan on running in the cloud, for now I'm running it locally.